# Are nested queries used for object mappings in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-dsl

Say we have a document model in ElasticSearch, which has a string (`registration`) and an object datatype called `currentname`, which then has a value called `name`. I have added model JSON in the bottom.

**How do you query this?**

Since the `metadata` item is not using the nested keyword, I assume we can get the data without the nested. However, since the `metadata` do have a properties value, I am unsure.

**My attempts:**

I have tried the simple model (NEST):

```
        var res2 = client.Search<dynamic>(s =>
             s.Index("myindexname").AllTypes().
                Query(q => q.
                    Bool(b => b.
                        Must(mu => mu.
                            Term(te =>
                                te.Field("metadata.currentname.name").Value(query))))));
```

This doesn't return any documents.

However, if I have to use nested queries, I don't completely understand why (is it because these objects are basically a different index?). And how would the DSL (or NEST code) look to do the right call?

**Document model:**

```
properties: { 
    Company: {
        properties: {
           registration: {
              type: "string"
           },
           metadata: {
               currentname: {
                   properties: {
                      name: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested query are used only with nested datatypes. Can you show the mapping of the index?

Comment: You can use `querystring` and search for `metadata.currentname.name: query`

Comment: Solved it. However, @DarioBalinzo - you basically answered the question. If you make a brief answer I will mark it. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested query are used only with nested datatypes